# $\pi ^+$ decay to $e^+ +e^+ +e^- +\nu_e$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

I was asked to give the Feynman diagram of the following weak interaction: $\pi ^+(u\bar d) \rightarrow$$e^+\nu_e e^+e^-$. I was asked to do this on the level of leptons and quarks. However, I could not seem to find it with the basic Feynman vertices. I thought a $\pi ^+$ only decays into $e^+ + \nu_e$ through a charged $W^+$ current ? When trying to draw the Feynman diagram, I cannot seem to get these two extra $e^+ + e^-$ out of it. Did I miss something ?

Comment: *I could not seem to find it with the basic Feynman vertices.* What vertices have you considered?

Comment: What does a virtual photon decay to?

Comment: @Ghoster , the charged current and flavor changing vertices of the weak interaction (for quarks and leptons).

Answer (score 1):

To give you a hint and not directly the solution: You say correctly that the decay happens via a $W^+$ ... which other interaction could be involved?

Comment: Well since there is an extra pair of electron-positron pair, I would think somewhere there would have popped up a photon that materialized. But that would be through the electromagnetic interaction, but the question also asked which kind of weak interaction this was (e.g. charged or neutral current, leptonic, semi-leptonic,...etc). So I didn't look too much into that.